# How do I remove a single record from MacOS local DNS Cache?

Tags: macos, dns, cache

I am working on creating and destroying VMs and their DNS records repeatedly to test something. I am able to remove single DNS records from the recursive DNS Server's cache, but I want to do the same on my local MacOS based machine.

I am aware you can flush the entire cache with:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I want to remove a single record. Similar to unbound's

```
unbound-control flush myhostname.mysubdomain.tld
```